# 500 Internal error - error TokenMismatchException

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Seem to be having problems with a TokenMismatchException on my Javascript button that are approving a comment. I have copied the code from a similar button system and changed it to match the requirements of this system. I am reusing the Session:Token variable, not sure if thats the issue?

```
Error: TokenMismatchException in verifycsrftoken.php line 68
```

Here is my code, any ideas on why i'm getting the mismatch error?

HTML:

```
@if(Auth::user())
       @if($approval)
         <a class="approval approved " data-id="{{$comments->id}}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
        @else
        <a class="approval not-approved " data-id="{{$comments->id}}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
        @endif

        @else
        <a class="not-approved" href="{{route('login')}}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
        @endif
```

Javascript:

```
        var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
        var urlApproval = '{{ route('approvals') }}';
        $('.approval').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var buttonToChange = $(this);
            var $this = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: urlApproval,
                        data: { comment_id: $(event.target).data("id")}, _token: token })

                    .done(function() {
                        if(buttonToChange.hasClass('approved')) {
                            buttonToChange.addClass('not-approved');
                            buttonToChange.removeClass('approved');
                        }else {
                            buttonToChange.addClass('approved');
                            buttonToChange.removeClass('not-approved');
                        }
                    });
        });
```

Comment: Try with `var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";`. I've never used `Session::token()` before, so maybe there's something happening there.

Comment: Tried that but doesn't work

Comment: Ah, I see it now: `data: { comment_id: $(event.target).data("id")}, _token: token })` `_token: token` should be inside of `data`; it's currently outside, so not being sent to the server.

Comment: yep i fixed that error with the doc code posted below. Now ive got a 401 unauthenticated error despite being logged in

Comment: Yeah, the code below prompted me to look a bit closer; both different ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ajax in laravel, and using POST method you always need to provide the csrf token, so what you need to do is:

In your HTML:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Before call Ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```